# daemon refusing to execute unsafe program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-daemon, start-stop-daemon

I want to start a service after my system start, here's my script in **/etc/rc.local** :

```
daemon /usr/bin/python /usr/local/google/home/yowang/Downloads/ftp.py > /var/log/pyftpd.log 2>&1
```

Error output at /var/log/pyftpd.log looks like this:

```
daemon: ignoring unsafe /etc/daemon.conf (/ is group and world writable)
daemon: fatal: refusing to execute unsafe program: /usr/bin/python (/ is group and world writable)
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess with permissions.

System is arguing that everyone (group and world) can write and change those files.

Try (su for root or prepend sudo):

```
#chmod 644 /etc/daemon.conf
#chmod 755 /usr/bin/python
```